# Use different MS Account between Office 2016 apps

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

My employer recently upgraded from Office 2010 to Office 365. The license for the core Office apps (Word, Outlook, Excel, etc.) is connected to my work email address. I also use Visio 2016, but this is not included in our O365 license. I have a license for it from my MSDN subscription. The MSDN subscription is tied to a different email address.

Is there any way to have Visio sign in with a different account than the rest of the Office suite?

Comment: I assume when you installed Visio it is forcing you to use the incorrect account?

Comment: Visio was installed first. It seems to share the login feature with the rest of the suite, so I get an "unlicensed product" message.

Comment: If you logout of the account then log into the correct account what happens to activation status Office?  Update your question.

Comment: It's weird...Office refuses to sign me in with the other account. It prompts for user, pass, and 2FA, and stays signed out. It's completely possible that the company's proxy is preventing the sign-in (although it did work before they pushed the update).

Comment: Sounds like you should seek assistance of one of your Administrators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must have been something with the proxy. I hopped onto a different network, grabbed a product key from MSDN, applied it to Visio, hopped back on the company network, and restarted the application. Now Visio shows me signed in as my company account, but using an activated copy that belongs to my MSDN account. Weird!